# Fetch API Data In Node JS and Save In MongoDB Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose

I'm new to mongooseDB and i'm trying to insert data from this API to the database, it creates the Collection but not the documents, any idea what could i be doing wrong?

````
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import mongoose, { mongo } from 'mongoose';

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/highscore");

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    position: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    score: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

});

const Post = mongoose.model('Players', postSchema);

async function getPlayers() {
    const getPlayers = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players");
    const response = await getPlayers.json();
    for (let i = 0; i < response.lenght; i++) {

        const post = new Post({
            position: response[i]['position'],
            id: response[i]['id'],
            score: response[i]['score'],

        });
        post.save()

    }
}
getPlayers();```
````

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo. `lenght`.

Comment: oh wow, fixed that one and still does not works.

Comment: checked mongodb connection url, changed to recommended and has the same outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import mongoose, { mongo } from 'mongoose';

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/highscore");

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    position: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    score: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

});

const Post = mongoose.model('Players', postSchema);

async function getPosts() {
    const getPlayers = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players");
    const response = await getPlayers.json();
    for( let i = 0;i < response.players.length; i++){

const post = new Post({
    position: response.players[i]['position'],
    id: response.players[i]['id'],
    score: response.players[i]['score'],
});
post.save();


    }

}
getPosts();
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB provides Api to insert many documents at the same time, example below.

```js
// check if your mongoDb is connected
mongoose.connect(URI).then(err => {
  if(err) console.error({err});
  else console.info("Database Connected");
});


async function getPlayers() {
    const getPlayers = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players");
   try{
    const response = await getPlayers.json();

    // And then check if you are getting players
    console.log({response});

    const posts = response.map((player) => ({
            position: player['position'],
            id: player['id'],
            score: player['score'],

        }))
   // it's not required to await it, just to be sure it did insert
  await Post.insertMany(posts);
  }catch(error){
    console.log({error})
   }

}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, i tried this, gives no error but it does not inserts documents.

Comment: I have edited the code snippet, try do some debugging.

Comment: check if you are getting a response data from the fetched Api before inserting into the collection and try deleting the collection

Comment: hey this code seems to work, but when i add "getPlayers();" at the end of the file i get this error :  error: TypeError: response.map is not a function at getPlayers, and without "getPlayers()" cant fetch the api

Comment: it also shows me the data from the API [nodemon] starting `node .`
{
  response: {
    serverID: 'us146',
    timestamp: '1666023716',
    category: '1',
    type: '0',
    players: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],

Comment: then it should be response.players.map();

Answer (score 0):

This line:

> for (let i = 0; i < response.lenght; i++) {

response.length

now your array is empty so the save never happens

**EDIT**

Are you sure about the imports?
Following code works:

```
//const fetch = require('fetch'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/highscore");

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    position: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    score: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

});

const Post = mongoose.model('Players', postSchema);

async function getPlayers() {
    /*
    const getPlayers = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players");
    const response = await getPlayers.json();
    for (let i = 0; i < response.lenght; i++) {
*/
        const post = new Post({
            position: '12',
            id: '15',
            score: '300',

        });
        post.save()

    } //} getPlayers();
```

[image]

Comment: someone else saw this typo and i fixed it still not inserts documents. thanks for answer

Comment: weird, i tried that code and wont work either, i;m going to reinstall mongodb and do it all over again. thanks really appreciate it

Comment: what version do you have?

Comment: (base) ~ ➤ node -v
    v18.0.0
    (base) ~ ➤ npm -v
    8.5.5

Comment: If the collection is created, mongo should not be the problem. Can I suggest adding something like this to make sure your DB connection is ok?

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/highscore')
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB...'));

Answer (score -1):

By default mongodb runs on localhost: 27017

Check your mongodb connection url

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/highscore')
```

Comment: It wouldn't be able to create the collection if it was a connection problem.

Comment: i though the same, it still creates the collection but not the documents, i been checking the code for a day now and still don't know why.

Comment: Try console logging the response.json() from the fetch URL, maybe it is not receiving any data from the fetch URL to insert into the database

Comment: i do get the data on console
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
{
  serverID: 'us146',
  timestamp: '1666012870',
  category: '1',
  type: '0',
  players: [
    { position: '1', id: '105162', score: '2184577809' },
    { position: '2', id: '105098', score: '1891541457' },
    { position: '3', id: '105170', score: '1808716778' },